# responseEntity.ok generate malform response body by duplicate it spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, record

I attempt to call a get endpoint. But it return duplicate object under my response, i don't know why Spring return those malformed objects

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v0/api/user")
public class UserResource {
  private final UserApplication userApplication;
  private final UserRequestResponseAssembler requestResponseAssembler;

  public UserResource(UserApplication userApplication, UserRequestResponseAssembler userRequestResponseAssembler) {
    this.userApplication = userApplication;
    this.requestResponseAssembler = userRequestResponseAssembler;
  }

  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) {
    UserCreationRequest userCreationRequest = this.requestResponseAssembler.toUserCreationRequest(userRequest);
    UserCreationResponse userCreationResponse = this.userApplication.createUser(userCreationRequest);
    EntityModel<?> model = this.requestResponseAssembler.toEntityModel(userCreationResponse);
    return ResponseEntity.created(model.getRequiredLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF).toUri()).build();
  }

  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<?> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") String userId) {
    UserResponse user = this.userApplication.findById(userId);
    EntityModel<UserResponse> entityModel = this.requestResponseAssembler.toEntityModel(user);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(entityModel);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/{email}", method = RequestMethod.HEAD)
  public ResponseEntity<?> existByEmail(@PathVariable("email") String email) {
    if (userApplication.checkIfUserExistByEmail(email)) return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND).build();
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
  }

}
```

this is a the userResponse record:

```
public record UserResponse(String userId,
                           String firstname, String lastname, String email, String profession) {
}
```

This is the User.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
  private Long id;
  @Embedded
  private UserInformation userInformation;
  @Embedded
  private AuditInformation auditInformation;
  @Embedded
  private UserId userId;

  @Embedded
  private AuthInformation authInformation;

  User() {
  }

  public User(UserInformation userInformation, AuditInformation auditInformation, AuthInformation authInformation, UserId userId) {
    this.userInformation = userInformation;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.auditInformation = auditInformation;
    this.authInformation = authInformation;
  }

  public UserInformation getUserInformation() {
    return userInformation;
  }

  public AuthInformation getAuthInformation() {
    return authInformation;
  }

  public UserId getUserId() {
    return userId;
  }

  public Set<Role> getActiveRoles() {
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    roles.add(Role.DEFAULT);
    return roles;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof User user)) return false;
    return getUserId().equals(user.getUserId());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getUserId());
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
        "id=" + id +
        ", userInformation=" + userInformation +
        ", auditInformation=" + auditInformation +
        ", userId=" + userId +
        ", authInformation=" + authInformation +
        '}';
  }
}
```

This is the UserId.class

```
@Embeddable
public class UserId {
  @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private final String id;

  public UserId() {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }

  public UserId(String stringUserId) {
    this.id = stringUserId;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof UserId userId)) return false;
    return getId().equals(userId.getId());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getId());
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "UserId{" +
        "id='" + id + '\'' +
        '}';
  }
}
```

This is the response of the get endpoint :

```
{
    "userId": "8db4c6ab-0872-4688-8cc2-26ea93019f78",
    "firstname": "wetryyuf",
    "lastname": "dtdddddddf",
    "email": "eleanr@waldorf.com",
    "profession": null,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/v0/api/user/8db4c6ab-0872-4688-8cc2-26ea93019f78"
        }
    }
}{
    "userId": "8db4c6ab-0872-4688-8cc2-26ea93019f78",
    "firstname": "wetryyuf",
    "lastname": "dtdddddddf",
    "email": "eleanr@waldorf.com",
    "profession": null,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/v0/api/user/8db4c6ab-0872-4688-8cc2-26ea93019f78"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why the response is duplicated.

I'm using Springboot with java 17.

I attempt to call a get endpoint. But it return duplicate object under my response, i don't know why Spring return those malformed objects.

It seems like the method is call twice.

This is an image of what happens after one call.

[The endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XuMf.jpg)

[The response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysAkK.jpg)

The ouput suggested that the method is call twice.

I should specify that the others endpoints is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Once check with database, May be same id is storing two times.
2. Also check your entity class and mapping if present.

Here Method is calling two times so most probably there are two records with same id.

Comment: 1. For the same proposition, the id is mark as unique. So there is no duplicate value in the database.

Comment: For the second proposition the UserApplication return only one value the user record .

Comment: once try by changing public ResponseEntity<?> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") String userId) to public ResponseEntity<EntityModel<UserResponse>> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") String userId)

Comment: I have already done that but is not change the output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my CustomAuthorization filter. I have reload the internal filter twice like this,

```
@Component
@WebFilter(filterName = "authorizationFilter", urlPatterns = "/*")
public class AuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private final AuthenticationUserService authenticationUserService;
  private final AuthenticationAssertion authenticationAssertion;

  @Autowired
  public AuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationUserService authenticationUserService) {
    this.authenticationUserService = authenticationUserService;
    this.authenticationAssertion = new AuthenticationAssertion();
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (
        this.authenticationAssertion.isUnAuthenticateURL(request)
    ) {
      final String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
      try {
        if (!authenticationUserService.hasBearerHeader(header)) {
          filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
          return;
        }

        final String token = this.authenticationUserService.getAccessTokenString(header);
        Token retrievedToken = this.authenticationUserService.retrievedToken(token);

        if (!this.authenticationUserService.validateToken(retrievedToken)) {
          filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
          return;
        }

        UserDetails userDetails = this.authenticationUserService.loadUserByUsername(retrievedToken.getUsername());
        this.setAuthenticationContext(userDetails, request);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      } catch (Exception exception) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        Map<String, String> responseBody = new HashMap<>();
        responseBody.put("error", exception.getMessage());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), responseBody);
      }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  private void setAuthenticationContext(UserDetails userDetails, HttpServletRequest request) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        userDetails,
        null,
        userDetails.getAuthorities()
    );

    authenticationToken.setDetails(
        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
    );

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
  }
}
```

By passing the doFilter inside an else statetment is working well now.

```
@Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (
        this.authenticationAssertion.isUnAuthenticateURL(request)
    ) {
      final String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
      try {
        if (!authenticationUserService.hasBearerHeader(header)) {
          filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
          return;
        }

        final String token = this.authenticationUserService.getAccessTokenString(header);
        Token retrievedToken = this.authenticationUserService.retrievedToken(token);

        if (!this.authenticationUserService.validateToken(retrievedToken)) {
          filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
          return;
        }

        UserDetails userDetails = this.authenticationUserService.loadUserByUsername(retrievedToken.getUsername());
        this.setAuthenticationContext(userDetails, request);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      } catch (Exception exception) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        Map<String, String> responseBody = new HashMap<>();
        responseBody.put("error", exception.getMessage());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), responseBody);
      }
    } else {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't hesitate to add comment in your code to highlight your solution